# How to display HTML tag within <pre><code>?

Tags: php, angularjs, html-escape-characters

I'm writing a blogging system, this will covert markdown file to HTML as published articles.

I face some problems when my markdown file contains something like this.

```
### ng-init

    <html ng-app>
        <body ng-init="customers=['Cust01', 'Cust02', 'Cust03']">
        </body>
    </html>
```

After parsing the markdown, I try to display the blog, this is the result.

[image]

> Of course I wish to display the whole set of HTML tag just like I can display them on stackoverflow.com

When I display the source it looks something like this.

```
<pre><code>
  <html ng-app>
    <body ng-init="customers=['Cust01', 'Cust02', 'Cust03']">
    </body>
</html>
</code></pre>
```

But if I take out the raw option of markdown parser the blog will display something like this instead.

[image]

Can I have exception for everything within the `<pre><code>` tag?, please guide how to fix this.

**Edited** This is my desire result.

#### ng-init

```
<html ng-app>
    <body ng-init="customers=['Cust01', 'Cust02', 'Cust03']">
    </body>
</html>
```

I would like **ng-init** to be displayed as heading 3, and the HTML part is displayed as code block

Comment: I'm confused. What is the desired result?

Comment: Sorry, I understood the question wrong. What is your code to render the markdown? And the css? Because your markdown is correctly rendered  elsewhere: http://jsbin.com/dogefuso/1/

Comment: The markdown is parsed correctly, but I guess the because of the `<html>` and `<body>` itself causes the problem, I just expected it can be exception when the tag lives inside `<pre><code>`.